# How to optimize compiling of 2D Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create a 2D Array that contains 9 arrays of 14 zeros. Currently, I have this written as:

`var sizes: [[Int]] = [[Int]](repeating:[Int](repeating:0, count:15), count:10)`

However, this single line sends my compiling time through the roof. How can I help the compiler to properly infer the type of the array so that comping does not take so long?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!
The image is of the expanded build log after the array is in the file.

[image]

Comment: Hmm – that compiles instantly in my Xcode 8.3.3 (but is 10 arrays of 15 zeros, not 9 arrays of 14 zeros :)

Comment: Interesting, because it presents me with 9 arrays of 14 zeros. Perhaps that is part of the issue.

Comment: How is the code in the build log (`init?(coder:)` etc) related to the array declaration in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
let sizes = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 15), count: 9)
```

Comment: This does not improve compiling time, unfortunately.

Comment: May you please explain more on how this does not improve compiling time?

Comment: I've added an image of the build log after the array is present in the file, this seems to be the effect of adding either array.

Comment: On second look over, the array does not seem to be the issue, however your syntax does work far better. Thank you!